# Can I charge my mid-2012 MBA using its USB 3.0 ports?

Tags: macbook-pro

My magsafe charger reached its peek. It doesn't work anymore. I'm looking for a way to charge it while I'm still waiting for my new one,  I was curious if I can charge it using the other ports it have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot charge it using its USB ports. In newer macs my understanding is that you can charge them with their USB C port. The only solution would be to order a new charger from Apple or pick one up from Best Buy. They’re about $100 USD or $125 CAD.